# Can/How Core-Plot extrapolate scatter points to fit fixed labeling policy?

Tags: core-plot, scatter-plot

**Situation:** Scatter points/date, each month could contain a *variable-number* of data (points).

**Desired:** Have fixed-width months along x-axis whose columns contain their respective points (i.e. *same-number* of points/month).

Can Core-Plot extrapolate missing data points to equalize the distribution of data/month?

How would that be done?

 
I want the fixed-width months to coincide/sync with their respective data points (and hence, may necessitate the filling in of missing data points; i.e., months with fewer points are padded with *extrapolated* points/data).

Answer (score 0):

Axis labeling is independent of the plot data. The labeled positions depend only on the plot range and the labeling policy in use. Core Plot won't modify your plot data—a plot only displays what you give it.

Comment: I've checked the release nots for Core-Plot.  In it is: "- **New**: Added Bezier curve interpolation option to `CPTScatterPlot`."  Being a neophyte, do you know if Core-Plot will be able to interpolate between data points to sync with its corresponding fixed-interval columns?

Comment: The Bezier curve option just draws a curved line between the data points. It doesn't add any points to the dataset. I don't expect that Core Plot will ever be able to interpolate plot data. It would be very hard to do something like that without knowing the details of your data. If you need to add data points, you'll have to determine them yourself and pass them to the plot with the other data.