# How do you use CPScatterPlotInterpolationLinear?

Tags: core-plot, interpolation, scatter-plot

I just happened to stumble across "CPScatterPlotInterpolationLinear" via google search for 'interpolation'.

Does this mean that I could plug gaps of scatter/linear data via interpolation?
I had asked a similar question earlier and was told that [CP doesn't add points to a graph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12662898/can-how-core-plot-extrapolate-scatter-points-to-fit-fixed-labeling-policy).

I attempted to create a 6-month fixed-interval scatter plot by creating an array of 180 elements for 180 days/6 months.  The missing data/day were filled with [NSNull null] objects... but CP merely plots the non-nulls without the interpolation.

The 'CPScatterPlotInterpolationLinear' enum got me to re-think.

**Question:** How do I employ 'CPScatterPlotInterpolationLinear' to interpolate missing data on a graph?  ... no need to actually add data points, just 'connect the dots'.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the line style on a scatter plot, Core Plot will connect the data points with a line drawn using the given style. The `interpolation` property controls how the points are connected:

- `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationLinear`: This is the default. Data points are connected with straight lines drawn directly between successive points.
- `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationStepped`: Steps are drawn beginning at each data point.
- `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationHistogram`: Steps are drawn centered at each data point.
- `CPTScatterPlotInterpolationCurved`: Data points are connected with a smooth curved line drawn between successive points.

None of these styles will add data points (i.e., points that can be indicated with plot symbols or data labels). They simply connect the data points provided by the datasource.